# jquery live change on inputs

Tags: jquery, html

i have more than 1 live change that monitors the input and replicates into another field - works great on the first name but any other field after that does not work for some reason.... anyone got any ideas?

```
$("input#same_shipping_address_first_name").live('change', function() {
    $('input#same_billing_address_first_name').val($('input#same_shipping_address_first_name').val());
});
$("input#same_billing_address_last_name").live('change', function() {
    $('input#same_billing_address_last_name').val($('input#same_shipping_address_last_name').val());
});
$("input#same_billing_address_address_line_1").live('change', function() {
    $('input#same_billing_address_address_line_1').val($('input#same_shipping_address_address_line_1').val());
});
$("input#same_billing_address_address_line_2").live('change', function() {
    $('input#same_billing_address_address_line_2').val($('input#same_shipping_address_address_line_2').val());
});
$("input#same_billing_address_address_line_3").live('change', function() {
    $('input#same_billing_address_address_line_3').val($('input#same_shipping_address_address_line_3').val());
});
$("input#same_billing_address_town_city").live('change', function() {
    $('input#same_billing_address_town_city').val($('input#same_shipping_address_town_city').val());
});
$("input#same_billing_address_county").live('change', function() {
    $('input#same_billing_address_county').val($('input#same_shipping_address_county').val());
});
$("input#same_billing_address_postcode").live('change', function() {
    $('input#same_billing_address_postcode').val($('input#same_shipping_address_postcode').val());
});​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you'd want to add the live listener to same_shipping_address_last_name, rather than same_*billing*_address_last_name, as it currently is.

Right now, you're just overwriting the value of a input whenever that input changes. In your first_name example, you're overwriting the value of *another* input when the input changes, which makes more sense.

You could probably address all of these inputs with just one listener, though. If you add the `shipping` class to the first set of inputs, for instance:

```
$(".shipping").live('change', function() {
    var billingId = $(this).attr('id').replace('_shipping_','_billing_');
    $('#' + billingId).val($(this).val());
});
```

You could of course do something like this without the class as well:

```
$('input[name^="same_shipping_address"]').live('change', function() { ... });
```

As others have pointed out, use `.on` or `.delegate` (depending on jQuery version) over `.live`.

Comment: I think `this.id` would also work in place of `$(this).attr('id')` but +1 as I was thinking the exact same solution

Comment: thanks worked a treat, had to use live as lower version being used but all the same works as expected - thanks

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for the successive ones because the first selector is `same_billing_x` where it should be `same_shipping_x`.

Also, the use of `live()` should be avoided. If you are using jQuery 1.7+ you should use `on()`, otherwise `delegate()`. Here's a modified example:

```
$("form").delegate('#same_shipping_address_first_name', 'change', function(){ 
    $('#same_billing_address_first_name').val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try using :

```
$("input#same_shipping_address_first_name").on('change', function(){
 .....
```